# Normalizar encoding de toda uma solução

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Estava trabalhando com GitLab e reparei que ele serve todos os arquivos em seu front-end com UTF-8.

Tenho uma solução que possui arquivos fonte com encodings diversos. Os arquivos em UTF-8 são exibidos corretamente no GitLab. Porém há arquivos com encoding Codepage 1252 e para esses os caracteres acentuados não são exibidos no GitLab.

Isso não me provoca nenhum problema na IDE, mas é um incômodo na hora de revisar código. Existe alguma funcionalidade no Visual Studio para normalizar o encoding dos arquivos?

Na ausência de uma funcionalidade dessas, existe alguma técnica ou boa prática para a normalização dos arquivos? (Além de definir seu encoding desde o início)

Comment: Você pode criar um código p/ fazer isso http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279673/save-all-files-in-visual-studio-project-as-utf-8/2633313

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não existe uma solução embutida para isso, mas como o Paulo falou nos comentários... Nós somos programadores, nós mesmos podemos resolver isso.

Segue minha solução, adaptada de [uma postada no Stack Overflow em inglês:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/850751/2263584)

```
foreach (FileInfo arquivo in new DirectoryInfo(caminho).GetFiles("*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
    string conteudoArquivo = File.ReadAllText(arquivo.FullName);
    File.WriteAllText(arquivo.FullName, conteudoArquivo, Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Onde `caminho` é a raiz da solução.